# Tuple and Function Argument in Swift

Tags: swift, tuples

In Swift, how is tuple related to function argument?

In the following two examples the function returns the same type even though one takes a tuple while the other takes two arguments. From the caller standpoint (without peeking at the code), there is no difference whether the function takes a tuple or regular arguments.

Is function argument related to tuple in some ways?

e.g.

```
func testFunctionUsingTuple()->(Int, String)->Void {
    func t(x:(Int, String)) {
        print("\(x.0) \(x.1)")
    }

    return t
}

func testFuncUsingArgs()->(Int, String)->Void {
    func t(x:Int, y:String) {
        print("\(x) \(y)")
    }

    return t
}

do {
    var t = testFunctionUsingTuple()
    t(1, "test")
}

do {
    var t = testFuncUsingArgs()
    t(1, "test")
}
```

There is also inconsistencies in behavior when declaring tuple in function argument in a regular function (rather than a returned function):

```
func funcUsingTuple(x:(Int, String)) {
    print("\(x.0) \(x.1)")
}

func funcUsingArgs(x:Int, _ y:String) {
    print("\(x) \(y)")
}

// No longer works, need to call funcUsingTuple((1, "test")) instead
funcUsingTuple(1, "test")   
funcUsingArgs(1, "test3")
```

**UPDATED:**

Chris Lattner's clarification on tuple:

> "x.0” where x is a scalar value produces that scalar value, due to odd
>   behavior involving excessive implicit conversions  between scalars and
>   tuples.  This is a bug to be fixed.
>
> In "let x = (y)”, x and y have the same type, because (x) is the
>   syntax for a parenthesis (i.e., grouping) operator, not a tuple
>   formation operator.  There is no such thing as a single-element
>   unlabeled tuple value.
>
> In "(foo: 42)” - which is most commonly seen in argument lists -
>   you’re producing a single element tuple with a label for the element. 
>   The compiler is currently trying hard to eliminate them and demote
>   them to scalars, but does so inconsistently (which is also a bug). 
>   That said, single-element labeled tuples are a thing.

Comment: In this function `func funcUsingTuple(x:(Int, String))` you have to explicitly pass a tuple: `funcUsingTuple((1, "test"))`

Comment: @Antonio Yes I already noted that.  Question is why do I not need to do the same when the same exact function is being returned from a function instead? (See earlier example)

Comment: @Boon, seriously, not even an up-vote for each of the substantial answers with associated discussion?

Comment: @GoZoner Thanks for the reminder, there were still on=going active discussions.  Upvoted your answer.  Hasn't selected an answer yet because no answer has covered the second part of the question.

Answer (score 4):

Every function takes exactly one tuple containing the function's arguments.  This includes functions with no arguments which take `()` - the empty tuple - as its one argument.

Here is how the Swift compiler translates various paren forms into internal representations:

```
() -> Void
(x) -> x
(x, ...) -> [Tuple x ...]
```

and, if there was a `tuple?` function, it would return true on: `Void`, `X`, `[Tuple x ...]`.

And here is your proof:

```
let t0 : () = ()
t0.0 // error

let t1 : (Int) = (100)
t1.0 -> 100
t1.1 // error

let t2 : (Int, Int) = (100, 200)
t2.0 -> 100
t2.1 -> 200
t2.2 // error
```

[Boldly stated w/o a Swift interpreter accessible at the moment.]

From [AirSpeedVelocity](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/08/02/tuple-wrangling/)

> But wait, you ask, what if I pass something other than a tuple in?
>   Well, I answer (in a deeply philosophical tone), what really is a
>   variable if not a tuple of one element? Every variable in Swift is a
>   1-tuple. In fact, every non-tuple variable has a .0 property that is
>   the value of that variable.4 Open up a playground and try it. So if
>   you pass in a non-tuple variable into TupleCollectionView, it’s legit
>   for it to act like a collection of one. If you’re unconvinced, read
>   that justification again in the voice of someone who sounds really
>   confident.

Remember the 'philosophical tone' as we've reached the 'I say potato; your say potato' phase.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case because you cannot have a single-element tuple, and a function can take a single argument.

Comment: That is an optimization - a one tuple of X is X.

Comment: So one tuple of X is no longer a tuple? reflect(x) seems to suggest so.  A tuple is an actual type, how can a single element tuple lose its type?

Comment: No, (x) is no longer tuple, it's x. Read the linked docs from my comment below other answer.

Comment: You are talking about an optimization; look at the grammar in your reference - zero or more arguments _is_ a tuple.

Comment: So my statement is correct - you cannot have a single element tuple.  The guide says: "you can name a tuple element only when the tuple type has two or more elements."

Comment: Given that a function can take single argument and a single argument cannot be a tuple, the conclusion is the function may or may not accept tuple, depending on how many arguments it accepts. Sounds right?

Comment: Nope.  A single value is a 1-tuple.

Comment: @GoZoner reflect() doesn't seem to suggest so.  Tuple is a type, the single value is either its actual type or a tuple type, it can't be both.

Comment: @GoZoner is right, grammar says it's still one element tuple. But the comment above grammar (in docs) says that the type (X) becomes X.

Comment: @Boon, yes it can be both.  Just like `x:Int` is both `Int` and `Any` (and maybe event `AnyObject` if Foundation has been imported).  My guess is `reflect(10)` doesn't mention `Any`?

Comment: @GoZoner Any is a protocol, so that's fine.  I don't think Tuple is though.

Comment: Check [this](https://gist.github.com/robertvojta/8ce4ab72ad8a87d32c7f). `oneSimple` becomes `@_Tv4main9oneSimpleSi` and `oneTuple` becomes `@_Tv4main8oneTupleSi`. `Si` is `Swift.Int` according to [Mike's post](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-15-swift-name-mangling.html). There's no `T` (= tuple). Which is there only for empty tuple (`T_`) or 2 (or more) elements `TSiSi_`. `emptyTuple` becomes `@_Tv4main10emptyTupleT_` and `twoTuple` becomes `@_Tv4main8twoTupleTSiSi_`.

Comment: I upvoted the answer but on second thought, there may be inaccuracy in saying every function takes a tuple as argument.  For example, tuples cannot represent inout parameters and variadic parameters.

Comment: No second thoughts please.  Maybe it is not the right answer; fine.  But it deserves an up-vote.

Comment: @GoZoner Second thought on accuracy.  You got your upvote.  Could you correct the main premise of the answer?

Comment: @robertvoja Thanks for the disassembly, upvoted.  This is inlined with what reflect() suggests so it's good to have this confirmation.

Comment: @robertvojta Question, why can we  access single element via .0 when it's not a tuple?

Comment: @Boon It's not disassembly. It's SIL (Swit Intermediate Language) and LLVM IR. Just pass -emit-sil or -emit-ir to swiftc. Compilation consists of several phases - Swift -> Swift AST -> SIL -> LLVM IR -> assembly -> binary. Why .0? Don't know the reasoning, ask Chris Lattner, but according to article written by Airspeed Velocity linked by Rob _Every variable in Swift is a 1-tuple. In fact, every non-tuple variable has a .0 property that is the value of that variable_. I take it as a fact for now.

Comment: You can find more details in [Thinking in Swift (Part II)](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/thinking-swift-part-ii/) article.

Comment: Thanks for the link @robertvojta

Answer (score 1):

A function in Swift takes a tuple as parameter, which can contain zero or more values. A parameterless function takes a tuple with no value, a function with one parameter takes a tuple with 1 value, etc.

You can invoke a function by passing parameters individually, or by grouping them into an *immutable* tuple. For example, all these invocations are equivalent:

```
do {
    let t1 = testFunctionUsingTuple()
    let t2 = testFuncUsingArgs()

    let params = (1, "tuple test")

    t1(params)
    t1(2, "test")

    t2(params)
    t2(3, "test")
}
```

Comment: A tuple has to have at least two elements.  You cannot have a single element tuple.  A function can take a single argument, so is the statement "A function in Swift takes a tuple as a parameter" accurate? Also, I posted example of inconsistent behavior with regular func taking tuple (vs. returned func), which is interesting.

Comment: `()` is a tuple - just a tuple with no value. The minimum number of values in a tuple is zero, not two - think of the `()` in `(Int) -> ()`: the return value is a tuple with no value (i.e. void)

Comment: I treat zero as a special case.  Once you have anything in a tuple, the minimum elements is two, you cannot have one element tuple - or so it seems.

Comment: Also notice in my last example, a function taking a tuple as an argument requires that you pass in a tuple, whereas the same function being returned does not, which is strange.

Comment: Check https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html - search for Tuple Type - _A tuple type is a comma-separated list of zero or more types, enclosed in parentheses._ - () no special case, empty tuple.

Comment: And _If there is only one element inside the parentheses, the type is simply the type of that element. For example, the type of (Int) is Int, not (Int)_

Comment: However `let x = 1; print(x.0)` works, which means `x` is both an `Int` and a tuple

Comment: Haha interesting test. It seems like tuple is a compiler magic, not a type in the strictest sense.

Comment: Every type can be automatically promoted to a one-tuple containing that type. This is very similar to the fact that every type can be automatically promoted to an Optional of that type. Tuples and Optionals are still types; they just have promotion rules. Airspeed Velocity did an excellent writeup of tuples here: http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/08/02/tuple-wrangling/

Comment: @Antonio Checked with Chris Lattner, apparently x.0 is a bug, not a feature.  So x is an Int and not a tuple.

Comment: @Boon so, not a 1-tuple :) No promotion to 1-tuple, just a bug. Good to know. Thanks for checking it with Chris.

Comment: @robertvojta Right, there is no such thing as an unnamed 1-tuple, but you can have a single-element named tuple, and this gets demoted by the compiler to a scalar.